# What is the max length for an Android app title in Chinese?

Tags: android, google-play, chinese-locale, double-byte

I know that the max. character length for an application title in Google Play Store is **30 characters**, see [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en) and [here](https://www.briggsby.com/how-to-optimize-your-android-app-for-google-play/).
However, how does this apply to languages that use double-byte characters, like Chinese? Would that be 30 characters as well, or fewer - does anyone know?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: Why don't you try it? Just copy&paste some gibrish. I'm pretty sure it's 30 unicode characters, at least when I wrote in Hebrew it was 30 chars.

Comment: No, it's 50 characters: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: Open Product details.